# Android Setting Listview Divider Height On Older Api

Tags: android, listview

This problem happens on older android devices(2.1, 2.2). But on new devices it works fine.
I want to set divider height of the listview after an animation. After user click a list item, the list item expands. after that when i call setDividerHeight method, listview returns older appearence. As if the expand effect never happen! What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: setDividerHeight was introduced on API level 1 so there must be another thing going wrong with your code! Try calling invalidate() after the end of your animation too!

Comment: i realized that before 3.0 when i call setDividerHeight method listview reset the list adapter and listview recreated. Bu t after 3.0 this does not happen. Can i fix that?